# How to create an adjacency matrix in pandas such that the labels are preserved when rows and cols are rearranged

Tags: python, pandas, categories, adjacency-matrix

I have never used pandas or numpy for this purpose before and am wondering **what's the idiomatic way to construct labeled adjacency matrices in pandas**.

My data comes in a shape similar to this. Each `"uL22"` type of thing is a protein and the the arrays are the neighbors of this protein. Hence( in this example below) an adjacency matrix would have 1s in `bL31` row, `uL5` column, and the converse, etc.

My problem is twofold:

1. The actual dimension of the adjacency matrix is dictated by a set of protein-names that is generally much larger than those contained in the `nbrtree`, so i'm wondering what's the best way to map my `nbrtree` data to that set, say a `100` by `100` matrix corresponding to neighborhood relationships of a `100` proteins.
2. I'm not quite sure how to "bind" the names(i.e.`uL32`etc.) of those 100 proteins to the rows and columns of this matrix such that when I start moving rows around the names move accordingly. ( i'm planning to rearange the adjacency matrix into to have a block-diagonal structure)

```
"nbrtree": {
        "bL31": ["uL5"],
        "uL5": ["bL31"],
        "bL32": ["uL22"],
        "uL22": ["bL32","bL17"],
         ...
        "bL33": ["bL35"],
        "bL35": ["bL33","uL15"],
        "uL13": ["bL20"],
        "bL20": ["uL13","bL21"]
}
>>>len(nbrtree)
>>>40
```

I'm sure this is a manipulation that people perform daily, i'm just not quite familiar with how dataframes function properly, so i'm probably looking for something very obvious. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, But from what I get try out this code.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import pandas as pd
dic = {"first": {
        "a": ["b","d"],
        "b": ["a","h"],
        "c": ["d"],
        "d": ["c","g"],
        "e": ["f"],
        "f": ["e","d"],
        "g": ["h","a"],
        "h": ["g","b"]
}}
col = list(dic['first'].keys())
data = pd.DataFrame(0, index = col, columns = col, dtype = int)
for x,y in dic['first'].items():
        data.loc[x,y] = 1
pp(data)
```

The output from this code being

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
a  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
b  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
c  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
e  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
f  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
g  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
h  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

**Note** that this adjaceny matrix here is **not symmetric** as I have taken some **random data**

To absorb your labels into the dataframe change to the following

```
data = pd.DataFrame(0, index = ['index']+col, columns = ['column']+col, dtype = int)
data.loc['index'] = [0]+col
data.loc[:, 'column'] = ['*']+col
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul! This kinda sorta gets half of the way there. 
What if now wanted to perform some row/col operations in scipy that would shift them around? 
Is there any way to preserve the "a"'s and "b"'s? I'm asking because when i do ```np.array(data)``` and log it, the labels are gone... Any idea?

Comment: There's no such way asSciPy library depends on NumPy, which provides convenient and fast N-dimensional array manipulation and the data we have here is a Pandas Dataframe. There is a way you can Incorporate or absorb these labels into the data itself, but I think it would cause a problem with your mathematical and scientific computations. Check the edit to do that.

Comment: Yeah, will have to figure something . Thanks a lot for the input!